# Flow - static type checking failing

Tags: javascript, flowtype

I am coming from the world of TypeScript so I am a bit puzzled why the following does not fail.

```js
class Bar {
  foo: string
}


let bar = new Bar();
let test = bar.foo;
test = 4; // all is good here, while it should fail!
```

Answer (score 0):

It's called class properties syntax https://flow.org/en/docs/types/classes/

In your example

```
class Bar {
  foo: string // not defined
}


let bar = new Bar()
let test = bar.foo // Copy value not type, should use let test: string = bar.foo
test = 4
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not fail because you have essentially defined the variable `test` as `any`. Types are not passed between variables when assigning values.

If you want to enforce variable `test` as type `string` you should define it's type.

```
let test: string = bar.foo; // ok
test = 4; // flow error
```

This should throw the following error

```
^ Cannot assign `4` to `test` because number [1] is incompatible with string [2].
```